# Repository and tag name <none> in docker image of go

Tags: docker, go

**go.mod**

```
module github.com/dhruv354/iitk-coin

go 1.13

require (
    github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible
    github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.14.0
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20210513164829-c07d793c2f9a
)
```

**go.sum**

```
github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery v1.5.1/go.mod h1:GsLWisAFVj4WgDibEWF4pvYnkVQBpKBKeU+7zCJoLcc=
github.com/andybalholm/cascadia v1.1.0/go.mod h1:GsXiBklL0woXo1j/WYWtSYYC4ouU9PqHO0sqidkEA4Y=
github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible h1:7qlOGliEKZXTDg6OTjfoBKDXWrumCAMpl/TFQ4/5kLM=
github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible/go.mod h1:E3ru+11k8xSBh+hMPgOLZmtrrCbhqsmaPHjLKYnJCaQ=
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.14.0 h1:mLyGNKR8+Vv9CAU7PphKa2hkEqxxhn8i32J6FPj1/QA=
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.14.0/go.mod h1:JIl7NbARA7phWnGvh0LKTyg7S9BA+6gx71ShQilpsus=
golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190308221718-c2843e01d9a2 h1:VklqNMn3ovrHsnt90PveolxSbWFaJdECFbxSq0Mqo2M=
golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190308221718-c2843e01d9a2/go.mod h1:djNgcEr1/C05ACkg1iLfiJU5Ep61QUkGW8qpdssI0+w=
golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20210513164829-c07d793c2f9a h1:kr2P4QFmQr29mSLA43kwrOcgcReGTfbE9N577tCTuBc=
golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20210513164829-c07d793c2f9a/go.mod h1:P+XmwS30IXTQdn5tA2iutPOUgjI07+tq3H3K9MVA1s8=
golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20180218175443-cbe0f9307d01/go.mod h1:mL1N/T3taQHkDXs73rZJwtUhF3w3ftmwwsq0BUmARs4=
golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200202094626-16171245cfb2/go.mod h1:z5CRVTTTmAJ677TzLLGU+0bjPO0LkuOLi4/5GtJWs/s=
golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200324143707-d3edc9973b7e/go.mod h1:qpuaurCH72eLCgpAm/N6yyVIVM9cpaDIP3A8BGJEC5A=
golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210226172049-e18ecbb05110/go.mod h1:m0MpNAwzfU5UDzcl9v0D8zg8gWTRqZa9RBIspLL5mdg=
golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190215142949-d0b11bdaac8a/go.mod h1:STP8DvDyc/dI5b8T5hshtkjS+E42TnysNCUPdjciGhY=
golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200323222414-85ca7c5b95cd/go.mod h1:h1NjWce9XRLGQEsW7wpKNCjG9DtNlClVuFLEZdDNbEs=
golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20201119102817-f84b799fce68/go.mod h1:h1NjWce9XRLGQEsW7wpKNCjG9DtNlClVuFLEZdDNbEs=
golang.org/x/term v0.0.0-20201126162022-7de9c90e9dd1/go.mod h1:bj7SfCRtBDWHUb9snDiAeCFNEtKQo2Wmx5Cou7ajbmo=
golang.org/x/text v0.3.0/go.mod h1:NqM8EUOU14njkJ3fqMW+pc6Ldnwhi/IjpwHt7yyuwOQ=
golang.org/x/text v0.3.3/go.mod h1:5Zoc/QRtKVWzQhOtBMvqHzDpF6irO9z98xDceosuGiQ=
golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20180917221912-90fa682c2a6e/go.mod h1:n7NCudcB/nEzxVGmLbDWY5pfWTLqBcC2KZ6jyYvM4mQ=
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.13


#Set the current working directory inside the container

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/dhruv354/iitk-coin

#commands
copy go.mod .
copy go.sum .
RUN go mod download

#copy everything 
COPY . .

#BUILD Executable 
RUN go build

EXPOSE 8080

#run executable
CMD ["iitk-coin"]
```

I am new to Docker and i am trying to containorize my golang application but it is giving me repository and tag name empty which i know indicates some error, i tried finding solutions on google but didn't find any so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [example from Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/) the following Dockerfile worked with one of my Go applications, try to adjust it to your case:

```
FROM golang:1.16
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . ./
RUN go build -o /myapp
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "/myapp" ]
```

Build:

```
docker build --tag myapp .
```

Run:

```
docker run --publish 8080:8080 myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe need to add this before download command:

```
ENV GO111MODULE on
```